# Is there any way to pass a mutator method as an argument to another method?

Tags: java, mutators

I'm creating a text based game, I have a class made for the main character so you can set the characters name, etc. What I'm trying to figure out is, is there any way to pass a mutator (character.setname(input)) as an argument to another method. When I try to do it I'm told that I can't use a void type as an argument to a method. When I was writing out the code for the user to enter their name, and everything else it was repetitive with the error checking so I wanted to create my own method I could call that would error check for me. A couple sentences use the setname method to reset the name if it was entered incorrectly but I can't directly use setname in the error checking method because it's going to be using the same method to check other inputs of data.

Is there any way around this?

Here is the code as requested: I indeed may be overcomplicating the problem, I'm pretty new to java so I'm still learning.

The following code is the code I use to check if the user entered something correctly, it accepts an array which contains all the possible correct answers the user can type in, I've tried to design it in a way that I can error check anything with it, not just "yes" or "no" statements, getVariable is the accessor method, and setVariable is the one I'm trying to get to work, I'm trying to pass the mutator as well so I can reset the error

```
public void confirmEntry(String question, String[] options, String getVariable, setVariable) throws InterruptedException
{
    boolean correctEntry = false;
    System.out.print("Is this correct? ");
    for(int i = 0; i < options.length - 1; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(options[i] + ", ");
    }
    System.out.print("or ");
    System.out.print(options[options.length - 1] + ": ");
    input = in.nextLine();
    for(int i = 0; i < options.length; i++)
    {
        if(input.equals(options[i]))
        {
            correctEntry = true;
            System.out.println(correctEntry);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(correctEntry);
    while(correctEntry == false)
    {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.print("You must enter ");
        for(int i = 0; i < options.length - 1; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("\"" + options[i] + "\", ");
        }
        System.out.print("or ");
        System.out.print("\"" + options[options.length - 1] + "\" to continue: ");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("You chose " + getVariable);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.print("Is this correct? ");
        for(int i = 0; i < options.length - 1; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(options[i] + ", ");
        }
        System.out.print(" or ");
        System.out.print(options[options.length - 1] + ": ");
        input = in.nextLine();

        for(int i = 0; i < options.length; i++)
        {
            if(input.equals(options[i]))
            {
                correctEntry = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The following code is what is currently in the method where you enter information about the character. I'm trying to move more of the code into the error checking method so that each time I ask the user a question, name, age, etc. I just simply need to call the method.

```
public void characterCreation() throws Exception
{
    //create an instance of the class player (your character creation)
    Player character = new Player();

    //Initial Introduction to the game
    System.out.println("Welcome to Stranded!");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    System.out.println("Tell us a little about yourself!");
    Thread.sleep(2000);


    //______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
    //SET YOUR CHARACTER'S NAME
    String[] yesNo = {"yes", "no"};                                         //array to feed into confirmEntry method
    System.out.print("Enter your character's name: ");
    input = in.nextLine();                                                  //asks for input of the name
    character.setName(input);                                               //sets name in the player class
    System.out.println("You chose " + character.getName() 
    + " for your character's name");                                       
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    confirmEntry("Enter your character's name: ", yesNo, character.getName(), character.setName(input));
    while(input.equals("no"))
    {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.print("Enter your character's name: ");                  //prompt to enter name again
        input = in.nextLine();
        character.setName(input);                                           //sets name in player class
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("You chose " + character.getName() 
        + " for your character's name");                                   //confirms what user entered for name
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        confirmEntry("Enter your character's name: ", yesNo, character.getName(), character.setName(input));
    }
```

I'm trying to move more code after the SET CHARACTER NAME comment into the confirmEntry method, however the rest of the code involved with the character's name uses the mutator to set the name. That's the problem. I wanted to try to get as much code into confirmEntry as possible so whenever I ask the user to enter something about their character I basically just have to call the method.

Comment: You should display some code. Sounds like you're going for a complicated solution to a simple problem, i.e. design issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
Also, I agree with Kayaman. This sounds like a design issue. My guess is that you can back away from the problem, abstract it to just the behavior that you want, and then come back in with a different strategy that may work better.

Comment: You can use a functional interface of some sort, eg Runnable, or you can write your own.

Comment: I tried to use Runnable but still couldn't get it to work.

Comment: What do you want confirmEntry to do?

Comment: I'd like to recommend against this design.  Value objects in your game, to the greatest extent possible, should be designed as immutable objects.  The simple fact of immutability solves so many scalability and maintability problems.  Example: your game begins as a simple text, turn-based game but later you wish to scale it into a "real time" world in which several players interact.  This problem is so much more complicated to solve if your domain objects are mutable.

Comment: Moreover, the methods you've shown us have a return type of `void`.  This is a possible code smell.  Methods that return no result can only affect a system via side effects.  Sometimes side effects are what you want, but over-reliance on them makes functional programming impossible to achieve and is antagonistic to good object-oriented solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **java 8** you can create your method with a method reference param  :

```
public void functionName(Consumer<String> setter){setter.
accept(string);}
```

and to call your **method** you can use : `functionName(character::setname);`

you can see : http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2171751&seqNum=3

Answer (score 0):

What is an entry? It appears to be some value that the user has entered.

```
class Entry{
    String value;
    public Entry(String value){
        this.value = value;
    }
    public boolean confirm(String input){
        return value.equals(input);
    }
}
```

How about you store all of your entries.

```
Map<String, Entry> entries = new HashMap<>();

String message = "Enter your character's name: ";
System.out.println(message);
String input = in.nextLine();

entries.put(message, new Entry(input));
```

Now when you want to confirm.

```
public void confirmEntries(){
    for(String message: entries.keySet()){
        System.out.println(message);
        System.out.println(entries.get(message) + "yes/no?");
        //get some input and update the value. etc.
    }
}
```

Another way to do it would be to create a Runnables.

```
List<Runnable> entryRunnables = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then anytime you want to add an action.

```
Runnable r = ()->{
    System.out.println("Enter your players name, yes/no");
    String input = in.readLine();
    //check input and do stuff.
}

entryRunnables.add(r);
```

Now to check entries. (stream method)

```
entryRunnables.forEach(Runnable::run);
```

Or

```
for(Runnable r: entryRunnables){
     r.run();
}
```